# Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: laravel, docker, elasticsearch

I have an issue according to elasticsearch, when I am running this command `php artisan index:ambassadors` inside docker, it gives me this exception.

```
**Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster**
```

Here is my output.

```
Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
  412/4119 [▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░]  10%Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
  824/4119 [▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░]  20%Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
 1236/4119 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░]  30%Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
 1648/4119 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░]  40%Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
 2472/4119 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░]  60%Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
 2884/4119 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░]  70%Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
 3296/4119 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░]  80%Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
 3997/4119 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░]  97%Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
 4119/4119 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓] 100%Exception : No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

[image: error message]

Also I have an error message in my elasticsearch container logs.

```
Some logging configurations have %marker but don't have %node_name. We will automatically add %node_name to the pattern to ease the migration for users who customize log4j2.properties but will stop this behavior in 7.0. You should manually replace `%node_name` with `[%node_name]%marker ` in these locations:
  /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/log4j2.properties.
```

Is there anyone who faced this issue before?